# Can't get past MessageSecurtityException()

Tags: c#, wcf

***I am fairly new to using APIs and WCF, so please let me know if I am leaving out any information.***

I can't seem to get past this issue.  I have two service references for this specific script and the calls I make for the first reference pass without error, however, the first time I try to call something from my second reference, the API throws a MessageSecurityError, specifically:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic Realm'.

```
 //Creating SalesOrder Client
    private static SoCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient CreateSalesOrderServiceClient()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 2;
        myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("address1");
        SoCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient client = new SoCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
        return client;
    }

    //Create OrderEntry Client
    private static DocCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient CreateDataWriteServiceResponse()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536 * 2;
        myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        myBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
        EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress("address2");
        DocCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient client = new DocCalls.SalesOrderServiceClient();
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
        client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
        return client;         
    }
```

and here is my config file:

```
<bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService">
              <security mode="Transport" >
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService1">
              <security mode="Transport" >
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
              </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="address1"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService"
            contract="SoCalls.ISalesOrderService" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService" />
        <endpoint address="address2"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService1"
            contract="DocCalls.ISalesOrderService"
            name="BasicHttpBinding_ISalesOrderService1" />
    </client>
```

Could anyone point out my errors or point me in the direction where I can find out how to progress?

Comment: If you get that error, you're successfully using basic authentication, but the wrong credentials.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well...I feel like a moron haha.  Let me check my credentials.

Comment: @CodeCaster If my `EndpointAddress`es are the same address, could that cause the issue?

Comment: @CodeCaster (sorry to spam you with notifications)  It was a blank space error...thank you!

Comment: Feel free to post that as a self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this error came from having the incorrect credentials in my second initialization:

```
CreateDataWriteServticeRepsonse()
```

Although the username and password looked identical to the first initialization

```
CreateSalesOrderServiceClient()
```

I simply copy + pasted the first username and password into my second initialization and there must have been a space or some type of mark that I did not see.